# I want to get json from api in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, dart-null-safety

```
class Phone{
int? id;
bool? is_new;
String? title;
String? subtitle;
String? picture;
bool? is_buy;
dynamic best_seller;
int? price_without_discount;
int? discount_price;

Phone({
  this.id,
  this.is_new,
  this.title,
  this.subtitle,
  this.picture,
  this.is_buy,
  this.best_seller,
  this.price_without_discount,
  this.discount_price
});
 factory Phone.fromJson(Map <String, dynamic> json) => Phone(
     id: json[MyPhoneKeys.id],
     is_new: json[MyPhoneKeys.is_new],
     title: json[MyPhoneKeys.title],
     subtitle: json[MyPhoneKeys.subtitle],
     picture: json[MyPhoneKeys.picture],
     is_buy: json[MyPhoneKeys.is_buy],
     best_seller: json[MyPhoneKeys.best_seller],
     price_without_discount: json[MyPhoneKeys.price_without_discount],
     discount_price: json[MyPhoneKeys.discount_price]
 );
}
```

(My screen to display the data)

```
class CarouselSliderData extends StatefulWidget{
  const CarouselSliderData({super.key});


  @override
  State<CarouselSliderData> createState() => CarouselSliderDataState();
}

class CarouselSliderDataState extends State<CarouselSliderData> {
  int? id;
  bool? is_new;
  String? title;
  String? subtitle;
  dynamic picture;
  bool? is_buy;
  dynamic best_seller;
  int? price_without_discount;
  int? discount_price;

  late Future<dynamic> phoneSpec;

  @override
  void initState() {
    phoneSpec = MyApiService().getDataMocky();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
          future: phoneSpec,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(snapshot.data!.id),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.is_new),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.title),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.subtitle),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.picture),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.is_buy),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.best_seller),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.price_without_discount),
                  Text(snapshot.data!.discount_price),
                ],
              );

          }



          );
  }

  Future<dynamic> getData() async{
    return await MyApiService().getDataMocky().then((value) async{
      if(value != null){
        setState((){
          id = value!.id!;
          is_new = value!.is_new!;
          title = value!.title!;
          subtitle = value!.subtitle!;
          picture = value!.picture!;
         is_buy = value!.is_buy!;
          best_seller = value!.best_seller!;
          price_without_discount = value!.price_without_discount!;
          discount_price = value!.discount_price!;

        });
        return value;
      }
    },
    );/*.catchError((_){
     throw Exception("Exception is caught");
   });*/
  }
}
```

(my service to get data)

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:my_work/apiService/model.dart';


class MyApiService{

  Future<dynamic> getDataMocky() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://run.mocky.io/v3/654bd15e-b121-49ba-a588-960956b15175')
  );

  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    return Phone.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)[1]);
  }
  return Exception();
  }
}
```

is my model right for this api json from [this api](https://run.mocky.io/v3/654bd15e-b121-49ba-a588-960956b15175).
I want to get data and display them in carousel Slider(i will add it) but get nulls. The Error is saying `Null is not subtype of String and nullcheck is used on NULL value` and i don't know why and where is my mistake. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Text` widget doesnt accept nullable string.

Instead of using `!` it would be better to check null first, or you can provide default value on null case. Format will be like

```dart
if(snapshot.data!=null) Text(snapshot.data.id),
```

Or

```dart
Text(snapshot.data?.id??"got null"),
```

Or  use String format like bellow, it will show null  on null case.

```dart
Text("${snapshot.data?.id}"),
```

I will recommend checking [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Thank you, i will try it. But the other parts is ok? I get nulls Why?

Comment: Could be issue on response data, some Fields might be empty `price_without_discount` and `discount_price` are empty on response and raise error,  .Also change `getData` methods variable same way, those already accept null data, It will be like `id = value?.id;` , didnt test but others might be ok based on error message

Comment: Thanks, i will try to do without errors

Comment: can you please explain to me one thing? I dont understand how to get List from api? I need to create model just dynamic or i need to do for all data that contains in the list?

Comment: your API returns  map, It can be `json.decode(response.body)["home_store"]` for getting `home_store` list, then generate list from this json  can be like `final result =  json.decode(response.body)["home_store"] as List?; final homeStoreItems =  result.map((r)=>Phone.fromJson(r)).toList()`, you can check [my sample note](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/master/jsonFormating/sample1.dart) and [networking/parsing](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it works, i got data but only strings. Because of Text Widget? Sorry if i asked a lot of questions. I'm a beginner

Comment: Text widget are used to show string on UI, you  can explore [/ui/widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets) to explore other widgets

Comment: glad to help, you can also check [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)

Comment: ok i will read what you sent